# looking for a standard theorem for comparison principle for ode

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

Consider
$$ y'_1(t)=f_1(t),\qquad y_1(0)=y_{10}$$
and
$$ y'_2(t)=f_2(t),\qquad y_2(0)=y_{20}. $$

If $f_1>f_2,\quad y_{10}>y_{20}$, then
$$y_1>y_2.$$

The above is what I was told by my advisor, could anyone let me know where in what textbook I can find a standard theorem to back up this claim? (I looked through several ODE texts but not able to find the right theorem.)

Comment: Also, probably mistagged as real-analysis and analysis.

Answer (score 0):

Just integrate
\begin{align*}
y_{k}\left(t\right) & =y_{k0}+\int_{0}^{t}f_{k}\left(s\right)ds
\end{align*}
and compare the two forms. You are assuming, implicitly, that the
$f_{k}$s are nice.
Then,
$$y_{1}\left(t\right)=y_{10}+\int_{0}^{t}f_{1}\left(t\right)dt>y_{20}+\int_{0}^{t}f_{2}\left(t\right)dt=y_{2}\left(t\right).$$

Comment: yes $f_k$s have to be continuous. Btw, what if they are not?

Comment: Actually, $f_k$s do not have to be continuous. Consider for example $f_{k}\left(t\right)=\begin{cases}
0 & \text{if }t<1\\
1 & \text{if }t\geq1
\end{cases}.$ Then, for $t\geq1$, $y_{k}\left(t\right)=y_{k0}+\int_{0}^{1}0dt+\int_{1}^{t}1dt=y_{k0}+(t-1)$. If the $f_k$s are not nice enough, you will not have nice solutions to your equations.

Comment: i was thinking about proving by contradiction...

Comment: Also, continuity is not enough to ensure that you have a solution. Consider for example $f_k\left(t\right)=1/t$. Also, you do not need to prove anything anymore, I have given you the proof.